# Is the Reverse Bits Solution Using Left Shift Results correct

Tags: javascript, node.js, data-structures, ecmascript-6

Trying to solve Reverse Bits Solution Using Left Shift Results ,problem says
`Reverse bits of a given 32 bits unsigned integer.`

```
Input: n = 00000010100101000001111010011100
Output:    964176192 (00111001011110000010100101000000)
Explanation: The input binary string 00000010100101000001111010011100 represents the unsigned integer 43261596, so return 964176192 which its binary representation is 00111001011110000010100101000000.
```

Here in the  solution  code loops 32 times,then doing left shifting of result,and then if `num & 1` is more than 0 `i.e. its 1`.then increment the result and also right `shift nums by 1` or `nums modulus 2` and then finally return the `result`

why the output coming as 0,`any thoughts and updated solution for this code`

```js
let reverseBits = function(nums) {

  let result = 0
  for (let i = 1; i <= 32; i++) {

    result <<= 1
    if (nums & 1 > 0)
      result++
      nums >>= 1

  }

  return result
}


console.log(reverseBits(11111111111111111111111111111101))
```

Output is shown as 0

```
PS C:\VSB-PRO> node Fibo.js
0
```

Comment: You are not passing the number you think you pass as argument. That is a decimal literal, not a binary literal.

Comment: Please be aware that if blocks _require curly braces_, if you need more than one line. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/if...else#description

Comment: Try `console.log(reverseBits(43261596))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some issues:

- The example value you pass as argument to your function, is not given in binary notation, but in decimal notation, so it is a different number than intended. Use the `0b` prefix for literals in binary notation.
- When using the `<<` operator (and `=<<`), JavaScript will interpret the 32<sup>nd</sup> bit as a sign bit. I suppose it is not intended to produce negative values, so avoid this by using a multiplication by 2 instead of the shift operator.

Not a problem, but:

- The `>>` operator will have a specific effect on numbers that have the 32<sup>nd</sup> bit set: that bit will be retained after the shift. As your script never inspects that bit, it is not a problem, but it would be more natural if 0 bits were shifted-in. For that you can use the `>>>` operator.
- Finally, it may be useful to output the return value in binary notation so you can more easily verify the result.

```js
let reverseBits = function(nums) {
  let result = 0;
  for (let i = 1; i <= 32; i++) {
    // use multiplication to avoid sign bit interpretation
    result *= 2;
    if (nums & 1 > 0) 
      result++;
    nums >>>= 1;
  }
  return result;
}

// Express number in binary notation:
let n = 0b11111111111111111111111111111101;
let result = reverseBits(n);
// Display result in binary notation
console.log(result.toString(2));
```